# injecting springbean into jsf managed bean?

Tags: spring, jsf

i put  class listners in my WEb.xml

```
<listener>
<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.
    RequestContextListener</listener-class> 
</listener>
```

in facesconfig.xml

```
<application> 
<el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
</application>
```

in applicationcontext.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.test.jsf" />
```

and to my managedbean in jsf

```
package com.test.jsf;

@ManagedBean
@Controller
@Scope(value = "request")
public class page1_backing
{
 @Autowired
 private UserInfo ui;

 ...
 }
```

but shows warning to add  handler. then i put

```
 <view-handler>com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler</view-handler
```

but it doesnt let me go smmothe.please help me to accomplish this task.

Comment: don't use JSF annotations but just spring annotation..leave all to spring

Answer (score 1):

Not just RequestContextListener. also add ContextLoaderListener.

```xml
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

And only use @Component annotation for managed bean,

```java
package com.test.jsf;

@Component
@Scope(value = "request")
public class page1_backing
{
    @Autowired
    private UserInfo ui;

    ...
}
```

it should work.